# Need help with jQuery hide/show

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to show and hide elements upon user interaction. The following code works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.c').hide();
    $('.b').click(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.parent().find('.c').show();               
    });
});
</script>

<div class="a">
    <a href="#" class="b">Show</a>
    <div class="c">This is hidden text</div>
</div>
```

But when i put the link inside a div tag the code does not work. I couldn't figure out the problem. So I'm expecting some help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.c').hide();
    $('.b').click(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    t.parent().find('.c').show();               
    });
});
</script>

<div class="a">
    <div class="d"><a href="#" class="b">Show</a></div> //if i place it inside div it doesn't work
    <div class="c">This is hidden text</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point out why it's not working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the containing div is no longer the parent of the link, it doesn't work to use `.parent()` to find it. Use `.closest('.a')` to find it:

```
t.closest('.a').find('.c').show();
```

This will work to find the element with class `c` in the same containing element, regarldess of what elements you put in there.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).parent()` is a `div.d`, not `div.a`, so it doesn't contain `div.c`, that's why `find('.c')` wont give you any elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you are doing a find() from the wrong place (div class=d) so you can't find (div class=c) from there.

Why do you need that anyway? Wouldn't it be simpler to just:

```
$('.c').show()
```

Comment: i can do that but i need to show/hide multiple elements in my actual code.